# Siteorigin widget cell spacing control

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, siteorigin

I'm working on a website using evolve theme in WordPress. I used inspect element to find various targets to customize several styles on the page. But despite searching quite a bit, I cannot find any control to remove the narrow cell spacing between the blue searchbox and the slider on this page:

http://orion.user.jacobs-university.de/wp/orion/

I am using the SiteOrigin builder widget for the layout of the page.

It would be great if someone could help me in finding which element must be targeted to remove this space. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above the div with `id="avartanslider-1"` there is a paragraph element with a bottom margin. If you remove this element it removes the gap.

[image]

The following Javascript will do the trick:

```
document.getElementById('avartanslider-1').previousSibling.remove()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!